# Hiding floating windows in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-juno

In Eclipse Juno if I edit a Java file in a maximized Java Editor and run a unit test the JUnit View shows up in a floating window.

[image: Eclipse Juno screenshot with a floating JUnit View]

The Java Editor remains active and the JUnit View hides half of my screen. How can I hide the JUnit window with keyboard shortcuts?

I've used Juno Service Release 1, Build id: 20121004-1855 and it's the same with Juno Service Release 2, Build id: 20130225-0426.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went the other way round - using keyboard shortcut to activate editor.

The default is `F12`, which I found too far to move my lazy finger to.
Instead, I rebound it to `Ctrl + ;`. Its very easy to reach out, and there is no other eclipse shortcut bound to this key combo (at least in my setup).

Comment: Thanks! This helps!!

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you are on Juno SR1. There were some fixes in SR1 related to floating windows. For me the JUnit window simply vanishes by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> or by focusing the editor again.

To ease your pain, maybe you also want to check "Activate on error/failure only" in the view menu of the JUnit view.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'm using SR1 and I've updated it too but the Java Editor still remains active.

Answer (score 1):

[Bug 391808](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391808) was reported about the Fast View not collapsing when clicking in the Java Editor. I just commented with this particular reproduction of the problem. I see the same issue as you working with Juno SR1. I have to actually click in the JUnit view before pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will work.